# Cross domain cookie transfer

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I have a referral link for example [www.example1.com?referABC](http://www.example1.com?referABC) of domain 1(example1.com). Now this referer text  should store in cookies of example1.com and when user click on button which re-directs to my 2nd domain [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) it should send cookies there , so that i can know that its the same user which was on first website.

I tried many methods but in 2nd website i am not getting cookies transfered from first, (sorry i am new here ) please help me

Comment: That's the neat part. You can't! In order to stop companies from tracking your activity across different websites browsers have implemented measures including not allowing a domain to set cookies for anything other than itself. What you're after is basically [OAuth](https://oauth.net/).